# I need Internet Security software with following properties

Tags: anti-virus, internet-security

I want to own an Internet Security software , but I prefer that it has following properties :

- Not a heavy one that killing the machine (Like Norton) .
- Delete the viruses , and don't keep it after clean it .
- **The most important off all** : Has an **Offline** databases that i can download and add to program database without connecting to Internet (Not Like KIS 2010)
- Containing (anti spam -anti Virus - Fire wall - .......  )

So what is in your mind?(Don't tell me AVG I tested it)

Comment: You could always do without a security suite and simply take your user out of admin and practice safe browsing habits. :) Just saying.

Comment: I use flash disks every day and need to clean it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

microsoft security essentials will work. its light, fairly effective and according to [this there's offline updates](http://computersservicing.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-download-virus-definition.html). You'd also need the mse offline installer (for [xp](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/3/8/A38FFBF2-1122-48B4-AF60-E44F6DC28BD8/mssefullinstall-x86fre-en-us-xp.exe) [32 bit vista and 7](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/3/8/A38FFBF2-1122-48B4-AF60-E44F6DC28BD8/mssefullinstall-x86fre-en-us-vista-win7.exe), [64 bit vista and 7](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/3/8/A38FFBF2-1122-48B4-AF60-E44F6DC28BD8/mssefullinstall-amd64fre-en-us-vista-win7.exe). Its just AV, but its about all i use.

Comment: thanx The Journeyman geek , in fact this product isn't Available in my country , and it's so simple that can't detect all viruses